# How to highlight multiple components for drag and drop file upload (Vaadin)

Tags: upload, drag-and-drop, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin to build my front-end and I want to upload files by simply dragging them from the desktop into the browser.

There are several components that can receive the file on the same page. So I used the DragAndDropWrapper on these components and implemented the DropHandler. When the user drags the file over one of the components, its style changes.

But I also would like the styles of all the components that can receive the file to get changed when a file is dragged over areas that cannot receive it, this way indicating the places the user can drop the file. Meanwhile, if the file is dragged over a receptor component only the style of this component should change again.

Is it possible to implement this using only Vaadin?

Comment: Had you a look at the easyupload addon?
https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/easyuploads

Answer (score 0):

Its possible. Add to the body of your page ondragover and ondragleave listener and style your multiple components when event fires. SSCCE:

```
    
@com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript("summer.js")
public class Valo4UI extends UI
{
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request)
    {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        Panel panel = new Panel("Login");
        panel.setSizeUndefined();
        panel.setContent(layout);
        TextField username = new TextField();
        username.setStyleName("canReceiveFile");
        layout.addComponent(username);
        TextField password = new TextField();
        password.setStyleName("canReceiveFile");
        layout.addComponent(password);
        Button ok = new Button("Login");
        ok.setStyleName("canReceiveFile");
        layout.addComponent(ok);
        setContent(panel);
        JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("initDragStyling()");
    }
...
}
```

summer.js:

```
function ohItsSummer(){
    var summerTable = document.getElementsByClassName("canReceiveFile");
    for(var i=0; i<summerTable.length; i++){
        summerTable[i].style.borderColor  = 'orange';
    }
}
function itsReallyHot(){
    var summerTable = document.getElementsByClassName("canReceiveFile");
    for(var i=0; i<summerTable.length; i++){
        summerTable[i].style.borderColor  = 'inherit';
    }
}

function initDragStyling(){
    document.body.setAttribute("ondragover","ohItsSummer()");
    document.body.setAttribute("ondragleave","itsReallyHot()");
}
```